# How to read temperature from ZTNQ-7020 Development Board?

Tags: vhdl

I have a small assignment that consists of reading the luminance from a sensor (GND, VCC, sig).

How can I connect the cables into the board? What constraints file should I have?

Has anybody found any example?

Thank you!

Here are the images of the board and sensor:

[board](https://ibb.co/XZ3V4jR)
[sensor](https://ibb.co/m4YHXF0)

Comment: Please improve your question. "GND, VCC, sig" is not enough. What type of interface is it, what is the protocol? Do you have link to the dev. board? Does that board have the required interface or do you need to write the HDL code too?

Comment: What is **exactly** your doubt on the assignment and what have you done so far? Also a quick google search shows several interesting [sources](https://www.google.com/search?ei=TApLXL-UDMfH0PEPkbO16As&q=ZYNQ+board+temperature+sensor&oq=ZYNQ+board+temperature+sensor&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30.10843.12967..13188...0.0..0.273.4109.2-16......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i19j0i22i30i19j0i22i30j33i21j33i160.2XLNOXAzcy0) - one even from Xilinx itself.

Comment: Dear Agazor, you are trying but it is not helping. I asked for the a **link** (specification) of the board and the sensor. Pictures do not help. The picture of the FPGA board has a brand for which I could do a internet search and find the specs. However that is YOUR task. The sensor is worse: There is no way to find out what it is. Look for the manufacturer on the PCB, go to their website and find the specs. Or ask whoever bought it where it came from. Without that you have no hope in hell to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

The XADC is component number 14 in the image below.

[Diagraman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nv0E.png)

So, I connected the sensor's pins to the board's pins(GND, VCC, sig).

After that, I created a module file and I configured the constraints file to map the AD14 pin.